# Searching for a better solution for aligning and centering the equations at the same time

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath, environments

```
\begin{gather*}
A^S_{\text{M.P.}} = \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} = \frac{0,66 \si{Bq}}{2,88 \cdot 10^{-3} \si{kg}} \approx 229,167 \si{Bq/kg} \\
\begin{align*}
\Delta A^S_{\text{M.P.}} &= \abs{\frac{\partial A^S_{\text{M.P.}}}{\partial A_{\text{M.P.}}}} \Delta A_{\text{M.P.}} + \abs{\frac{\partial A^S_{\text{M.P.}}}{\partial m_{\text{M.P.}}}} \Delta m_{\text{M.P.}} \\
                         &= \frac{\Delta A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} + A_{\text{M.P.}} \cdot m^{-2}_{\text{M.P.}} \cdot \Delta m_{\text{M.P.}} \\
                         &= \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \cdot \frac{\Delta A_{\text{M.P.}}}{A_{\text{M.P.}}} + \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \cdot \frac{\Delta m_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \\
                         &= A^S_{\text{M.P.}} \qty(\frac{0,14}{0,66} + \frac{\Delta 0,03}{2,88})
\end{align*}
\end{gather*}
```

With the code above, I get this

[image]

The value (the first row) is now in the middle of the page. Its error is aligned but not centered. I would like to put the error also in the middle of the page, so I have used three times \qquad.

```
\begin{gather*}
A^S_{\text{M.P.}} = \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} = \frac{0,66 \si{Bq}}{2,88 \cdot 10^{-3} \si{kg}} \approx 229,167 \si{Bq/kg} \\
\begin{align*}
\Delta A^S_{\text{M.P.}} &= \abs{\frac{\partial A^S_{\text{M.P.}}}{\partial A_{\text{M.P.}}}} \Delta A_{\text{M.P.}} + \abs{\frac{\partial A^S_{\text{M.P.}}}{\partial m_{\text{M.P.}}}} \Delta m_{\text{M.P.}} \qquad \qquad \qquad \\
                         &= \frac{\Delta A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} + A_{\text{M.P.}} \cdot m^{-2}_{\text{M.P.}} \cdot \Delta m_{\text{M.P.}} \\
                         &= \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \cdot \frac{\Delta A_{\text{M.P.}}}{A_{\text{M.P.}}} + \frac{A_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \cdot \frac{\Delta m_{\text{M.P.}}}{m_{\text{M.P.}}} \\
                         &= A^S_{\text{M.P.}} \qty(\frac{0,14}{0,66} + \frac{\Delta 0,03}{2,88})
\end{align*}
\end{gather*}
```

(At the end of the 4th row there are three more \qquad.) 
Now I get this

[image]

But are there any "automatic" ways to center those equations in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `aligned` block to within your `gather*` if you want a centered alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\
  \begin{aligned}
    g(x) &= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \dots \\
         &= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \dots
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```